# Creating a neural network in keras to multiply two input integers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am playing around with Keras v2.0.8 in Python v2.7 (Tensorflow backend) to create small neural networks that calculate simple arithmetic functions (add, subtract, multiply, etc.), and am a bit confused. The below code is my network which generates a random training dataset of integers with the corresponding labels (the two inputs added together):

```
def create_data(low, high, examples):

    train_data = []
    label_data = []

    a = np.random.randint(low=low, high=high, size=examples, dtype='int')
    b = np.random.randint(low=low, high=high, size=examples, dtype='int')

    for i in range(0, examples):
        train_data.append([a[i], b[i]])
        label_data.append((a[i] + b[i]))

    train_data = np.array(train_data)
    label_data = np.array(label_data)

    return train_data, label_data

X, y = create_data(0, 500, 10000)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=2))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=10)

test_data, _ = create_data(0, 500, 10)
results = model.predict(test_data, batch_size=2)

sq_error = []
for i in range(0, len(test_data)):
    print 'test value:', test_data[i], 'result:', results[i][0], 'error:',\
          '%.2f' %(results[i][0] - (test_data[i][0] + test_data[i][1]))
    sq_error.append((results[i][0] - (test_data[i][0] + test_data[i][1])))

print '\n total rmse error: ', sqrt(np.sum(np.array(sq_error)))
```

This trains perfectly well and produces no unexpected results. However, when I create the training data by multiplying the two inputs together the model's loss for each epoch stays around 7,000,000,000 and the model does not converge at all. The data creation function for this is as follows:

```
def create_data(low, high, examples):

    train_data = []
    label_data = []

    a = np.random.randint(low=low, high=high, size=examples, dtype='int')
    b = np.random.randint(low=low, high=high, size=examples, dtype='int')

    for i in range(0, examples):
        train_data.append([a[i], b[i]])
        label_data.append((a[i] * b[i]))

    train_data = np.array(train_data)
    label_data = np.array(label_data)

    return train_data, label_data
```

I also had the same problem when I had training data of a single input integer and created the label by squaring the input data. However, it worked fine when I only multiplied the single input by a constant value or added/subtracted by a constant.

I have two questions:

**1)** Why is this the case? I assume it has something to do with the fundamentals of neural networks, but I can't work it out.

**2)** How could I adapt this code to train a model that multiplies two input numbers together.

The network architecture (2 - 3 - 5 - 3 - 5 - 1) is fairly random right now. I've tried lots of different ones varying in layers and neurons, this one just happened to be on my screen as I write this and got an accuracy of 100% for adding two inputs.

Comment: I really don't think you need that many layers for that simple of a problem.  I tend to start with an input, single hidden layer, and an output, and add hidden layers until my accuracy stops increasing.

Comment: @D.Griffiths are you just looking for GPU acceleration for multiplication? If so, why not just use numba or some other simple GPU wrapper?

Comment: @chrisz this was just a random architecture, I have tried with much smaller networks (i.e. 2 - 3 - 1 etc.). It still gives incredibly high losses.

Comment: @duhaime I'm not doing this for any practical purposes just wanted to have a play around at writing networks in keras that learn something and play around with hyper-parameters to try and improve my understanding.

Comment: @D.Griffiths Could you please share with us how you changed the network to multiply two input integers. Looks like you figured out how to do that after an answer was accepted, please share, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to large gradient updates caused by large numbers in training data. When using a neural network, you should first ensure that the training data falls in a small range (usually [-1,1] or [0,1]) to help the optimization process and prevent disruptive gradient updates. Therefore, you should first normalize data. In this case, one good candidate would be [log-normalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/217703/114422).

Further, the `'accuracy'` as a metric in Keras is used in case of a **classification** problem. In a regression problem, using it does not make sense, and instead it's better to use a relevant metric like "mean absolute error" or `'mae'`.

Comment: I am solving this problem using normalizing input1 and input2 as (xi-min(xi))/ (max(x)-min(x)). Should I normalize Y also in same way. Then how can I bring value of Y back to real value.

Comment: @DreamerP It might not be necessary to do so. However, you can get back the actual value by: `pred * (max(y) - min(y)) + min(y)`, where `pred` is the prediction.

Comment: If I do not  normalize Y then what should we take value of Y in training. The value after multiplying x1 and x2 or value after multiplying x1_norm * x2_norm.

Comment: @DreamerP In that case you definitely need to use the actual value, i.e. `x1 * x2`, as the labels. If you use `x1_norm * x2_norm` it would not make sense since you want to know the result of multiplication above all! Of course, if you normalize `x` values by dividing by a constant then it is OK to use normalized multiplication result as well, since you can get back the actual value (i.e. by multiplying it by `constant * constant`).

Comment: Okay. So I need to train my model taking x1_norm,x2_norm,Y as normalized value of x1 and x2 and Y=x1*x2 as dependent variable. Will it approximate to desired output?

Comment: @DreamerP Yeah, `x1_norm` and `x2_norm` as input and `y = x1 * x2` (or `y = x1_norm * x2_norm` if the normalization scheme used is such that you can get back the actual value of `y`) as the output. However, note that normalization of `y` values might help a lot (and even extremely necessary) if it consists of very large values (say > 100 or 1000).

Comment: In that case  y=x1_norm*x2_norm will not work because say if x1_norm =0 then y=0 and also if x2_norm=0 then also y=0 so we can't get back y. however if we use y=y_norm (that is yi-min(yi) / max - min ) then that may work. But not sure so asked.

Comment: @DreamerP Yeah, that's why I mentioned you need to use a proper normalization scheme and it depends on it. And that's why I referred to log-normalization in my answer as a good scheme in this case. Normalization in this particular (and simple) problem plays a crucial role.

Comment: okay. If we log normalization then training set would be log(x1), log(x2) and dependent variable would be y=log(x1)+log(x2) but as x1 and x2 grows large the y value will also grow... Right?

Comment: @DreamerP Of course, but very slowly since `log(4 * 10^9) ~= 32`. Even then, you can further normalize the values if necessary.